# Operador Bitwise

Tags: javascript, jquery

¡Hola! Vi en diferentes sitios (sobre todo en otros lenguajes) código con el operador bitwise, pero ¿sabrían decirme cuál es su utilidad actualmente? o donde se podría utilizar, ya que para mí tendría sentido su uso en CPUs antiguas en donde no se podía permitir utilizar demasiados recursos de la misma.

Gracias! :)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Los puedes usar en muchos contextos para mejorar/abreviar el código, [aquí te explican algunos de ellos](https://blog.logrocket.com/interesting-use-cases-for-javascript-bitwise-operators/).